# phpmyadmin returns query results but php returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've spent the past couple hours combing this site and the web for a solution to my problem.  I'm certain it is an issue of syntax, and that it's a simple fix.  When running the following query in phpmyadmin, I get the desired results.  I'm joining two tables and displaying sums from each.  I used phpmyadmin to generate php code but return 0 lines.  Changing the SELECT query in php to a simple line which gathers only the sum and records from one table outputs multiple rows.  It is only when I use the multiple SELECTS from the more advanced query that I get no results.

```
SELECT
od.orderID,
od.owed,
od.freight,
op.paid
FROM
(
    SELECT
        acct,
        orderID,
        SUM(price * qty) AS owed,
    freight
    FROM
        old_details
    GROUP BY
        orderID
) AS od
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        orderID,
        SUM(payment) AS paid
    FROM
        old_payment
    GROUP BY
        orderID
) AS op ON (op.orderID = od.orderID)
WHERE od.acct='AS3576E'
```

The PHP script is...

```
<?php

include_once "connect.php";

$cID = 'AS3576E';


$query = "SELECT od.orderID, od.owed, od.freight, op.paid
FROM ( SELECT acct, orderID, SUM(price * qty) AS owed, freight
FROM old_details
GROUP BY orderID ) AS od
INNER JOIN (
SELECT orderID, SUM(payment) AS paid
FROM old_payment
GROUP BY orderID ) AS op ON (op.orderID = od.orderID)
WHERE od.acct='$cID'";

$line=0;

$results = mysqli_multi_query($link, $query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
echo "oid$line=$row[orderID]&";
echo "odate$line=$row[invDate]&";
echo "oowed$line=$row[owed]&";
echo "opaid$line=$row[paid]&";
echo "ofreight$line=$row[freight]&";

$line++;
}


echo "line=$line";


mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

I have tried mysqli_multi_query and mysqli_query.  I have tried many different tweaks.  There isn't a problem connecting to the database, as a change in the php query outputs rows of data.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_multi_query()`?

Comment: And if you're using MySQLi, why aren't you using a prepared statement with bind variables?

Comment: This is not a `multi_query()`. Have you checked the return status of `mysqli_query()` and possibly `mysqli_error()` to see if MySQL is objecting to something?

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm not sure what the point of using prepared statements is if you're not accepting user input. Are you worried about not sanitizing your own code

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - Get in the habit of using bind variables, and you won't forget to do so when it does matter

Comment: I wonder if your first GROUP BY is returning different results from phpMyAdmin. other than that i can't think of why it shouldn't return same results.

Comment: An unrelated problem: you want `mysqli_fetch_assoc` or `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` in order to get those echoes to work.

Comment: What are the ampersands for in `echo "oid$line=$row[orderID]&";` etc. ?

Comment: continuing with @Fred-ii- 's comment doesn't orderID need to be in some sort of quotes?

Comment: also there is no `invDate` selected in the query.

Comment: Well people, looks like this one's a `Hit 'n Run`. All sorts of comments and answers, and the OP's run off in 'dem dar Hills. Maybe he'll get us all dinner!? Let's just hope we're not having "Possum Pie".

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `mysqli_multi_query` here.  Even though you use subselects, this is still only a single query with a single result set usuitable for use with `mysqli_query()`.  If one were to use `mysqli_multi_query`, you would need to use `mysqil_use_result()` or `mysqli_store_result()` to work with the result set(s).

Also, you should get in the habit of actually checking for and logging errors when working with the database.  Here you start trying to work with `$results` before you even bother to check whether it contains a valid resource for the result set.

Comment: Good advice, but neither comment is an answer to the OPs problem

Comment: @MikeW Well yes and no.  The fact that he is using multi query without using proper use/store result function to work with the result set is a problem.  I added that here. My main intention was to suggest to the poster to just use `mysqli_query()` in this case.

Comment: OP has tried both `mysqli_query()` and `mysqli_multi_query()` - he says so in his post.

Comment: @MikeW Ah didn't see that at first. Well I guess we won't know what the problem is until error handling is added...